# How to launch a Python interpreter from a C extension

Tags: python, c, multithreading, python-c-api, python-embedding

I have a C script,

```
#include "main.h"


static const char *path_here = "./path/to/here";

static PyConfig py_config;

extern PyObject *fn_arg;


void *init_Python(void *) {

    pthread_cleanup_push(del_Python, NULL);

    /* Set-up the Python interpreter */
    PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&py_config);
    setenv("PYTHONPATH", path_here, true);
    PyConfig_SetString(&py_config, &py_config.program_name, (wchar_t *)path_here);
    if (PyStatus_Exception(Py_InitializeFromConfig(&py_config)))
        del_Python(NULL);
    PyConfig_Clear(&py_config);

    /* Run the Python script */
    PyObject *fn_def = PyObject_GetAttrString(PyImport_ImportModule("test_module"), "test_function");
    if (!PyObject_CallOneArg(fn_def, fn_arg))
        del_Python(NULL);

    pthread_cleanup_pop(NULL);

    return NULL;
}


void del_Python(void *) {
    PyConfig_Clear(&py_config);

    /* ... cleanup in Python with e.g. PyRun_String() ... */

    Py_Finalize();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

which I want to `pthread_create` from another file. The Python module `test_module` contains a function, `test_function`, which functions as a context manager for a blocking I/O operation and is called from C using `PyObject_CallOneArg`.

How do I raise an exception in `del_Python` from C using e.g. `PyRun_SimpleString` to tell `test_function` to perform a cleanup?

I've tried to do something simple, i.e. change a variable, to test this out. However, `PyRun_SimpleString("print(locals())");` reports garbage and even `PyRun_String` with `PyEval_GetLocals()` and `PyEval_GetGlobals()` fails silently when I attempt this (even though their respective dictionaries *are* populated properly with the relevant names). Ideally, I would want the Python interpreter to be "interrupted" and execute Python Bytecode compiled from C verbatim.

Furthermore, `Py_Finalize()` segfaults. Acquiring the GIL with `PyGILState_Ensure()` before calling `Py_Finalize` is a temporary fix but throws many Valgrind errors which all seem to relate to `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault`.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9531945/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595222/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625584/),  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427002/) question but still can't figure it out. Did I simply skip over the solution or am I fundamentally misunderstand something? Can anybody please help me out?

Note: the "in 2023" in the title referred to most of the functions in the aforementioned questions being deprecated or removed entirely.

Comment: There's a lot here that doesn't make sense. Why would a *module* define `__call__`? How would that function as a context manager? Why are you trying to raise an exception at all, let alone in the middle of code you clearly want to keep executing after that point?

Comment: I have no control over the nomenclature of the Python code. I've changed ```__call__``` to ```test_function``` to avoid further confusion.  I presume the context manager has been created with the ```context.lib.contextmanager``` decorator. I want to raise an exception to trigger cleanup which depends on the type of signal received rather than just kill the interpreter.

Comment: Looking at the `pthread_cleanup_push(del_Python, NULL);`... are you trying to *cancel* a thread while it's executing Python code? That's going to make an unrecoverable mess of your Python interpreter state. CPython is not designed to handle that.

Comment: Well, I guess that's exactly what I want to do ;) I'd like to run some code, depending on the kind of signal that has been received, _before_ the thread kills itself. But I should have full control over the code executed before that point in time, right? What's the difference between that and e.g. intercepting a ```KeyboardInterrupt``` from Python directly?

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` already has a nasty tendency to make an unrecoverable mess of whatever data structures a Python program is working with when it arrives, but at least it can't wreck the interpreter itself. It doesn't force-abort a thread's execution, and it can only arrive right before Python executes a new bytecode instruction, not in the middle of arbitrary C-level work.

Comment: But how does this force-abort a thread's execution? The thread is not exited until the end of the ```del_Python``` call. Is it not possible to somehow save the state of the interpreter/subinterpreter, "inject" new bytecode to raise whatever exception is necessary, have the relevant except clause clean it up, ```return``` to C, and shut down the interpreter gracefully?

Comment: The process of unwinding the Python stack requires unwinding the *C* stack too. They're very closely tied together. You can't do that from a pthread cancellation handler. Plus, even if you could, you'd be interrupting at some unsafe point that was not designed to be interrupted that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253299/discussion-between-user169291-and-user2357112).